# Change IP settings programmatically in Linux with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, ip

How to change the IP settings [mainly IP address, subnet mask and default gateway] in Linux using C/C++ ? I've seen examples that uses sockets but there are not much [besides they don't work]. I've tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652384/how-to-set-the-ip-address-from-c-in-linux) but it does not work.

Whenever I try the code I use ifconfig to see my network configuration but they are still the same. I have openSUSE 13.2 and have both wireless and ethernet available connections.

I think another solution would be is to change the corresponding script file for the interface but I can't find these script files' locations.

Comment: Did you try to run your application with `root` rights? There is no other way in my opinion to change it through `C/C++` but use linux/unix headers and libs.

Comment: mmm, good question. Let me try it.

Comment: Initially it worked! I will do further testing to make sure. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, such kind of operations requires root access. Run your application with root rights and it'll make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have two questions; Number one is how to set the default gateway ? And number two in the question I mentioned why there is a suggestion to use 'struct sockaddr_in*' instead of 'struct ifreq' ? I mean the second one worls for me.

Comment: Setting default gateway I believe is explained [here](http://www.unix.com/programming/142516-set-host-default-gateway-c-program.html). Second question - don't know. Comment a post there and ask a guy who proposed that. Good luck.

Comment: the code you provided works fine but it adds another route. Can I change the current default gateway not adding a new one ?

Comment: Maybe you have to remove default gateway first then? Also, here is another [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-to-set-gateway-using-c-program-846692/). Don't shy to google it, it can be easily googled.