# What ip address blocked when i try to log in to website?

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, ip-address

When i try to log in to a website after a few times my ip is blocked .
I tried to search a material on this subject and haven't found

1)which ip address is blocked(there is the one of the network and the one i can get from www.findmyip.com)

2)how can i change it ? Can i change it by using c programming?

I need this info because a project i need to make of security in the network.

***another question
Can i connect between computers that location far away from each other? What ip address takes a place

Comment: The website can only know about your external ip ( the ip address that the world knows about ), so that's what it's blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you need an intro to DNS. The IP address you see at findmyip.com is the address of your router / modem / etc. on your ISPs network. To change that, you need to send your traffic through a VPN. It's not something you can do at the application level (in your C code).

When you send traffic through a VPN, you're rerouting the requests you make to websites from your own computer through another IP. That machine then completes the request and sends you back the response.

You can either host a VPN yourself on another server or better yet, sign up for a VPN that allows you to refresh your IP. I've used HideMyAss in the past.

When you're on a local network, you indeed can control the address of your network adapter. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652384/how-to-set-the-ip-address-from-c-in-linux) should help.