# How to know the set for IP address from C in linux is successful or fail

Tags: c, linux, networking

I use this code to setup the IP address

```
int
set_ip(const char *name, const char *ip)
{
  struct ifreq ifr;
  struct sockaddr_in *addr;
  int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);

  ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

  addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;

  /* inet_pton() returns 1 on success */
  /* network address was successfully converted */
  int s;
  s = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr->sin_addr);
  if (s <= 0) {
    if (s == 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "Set IP %s not in presentation format\n", ip);
    else
      perror ("inet_pton");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);

  ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
  ifr.ifr_flags |= (IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING);

  ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is modified from here [How to set the IP address from C in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6652384/3309645).

My question is

How to know the ip address change successfully or not? Because the return value of ioctl always be 0.

```
$ uname -a
Linux DMA1 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have googled for hours but not found any solutions. So I post my question in here to ask experts in SO. Thanks in advance

Comment: By checking the return value of the `ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr)`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I checked, but even set ip address as 192.168.1.abc, ioctl return 0.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Maybe I need to check the name in inet_pton first

Comment: Why don't you query the ip address to see if it's the one you requested?

Comment: @charles.cc.hsu: No, your code checks the return value of `ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr)`, and that is a completely unrelated operation. If you did actually add the proper error checks, modify your question to reflect the actual code you used.

Comment: @k_kaz Yes, you are right. I should query the ip address to check if it is the same as I requested. There is no any error code return, the `inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr->sin_addr);` also return 0 even i set the address is `a.b.c.d`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal When I forget to assign a root privilege to the code, I will get `Operation not permitted` perror

Comment: Refer to man inet_pton, `inet_pton() returns 1 on success (network address was successfully converted)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, below is the solution suggested by you experts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/route.h> // struct rtentry
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int 
set_addr (const char *name, const char *ip, unsigned long request)
{
  struct ifreq ifr;
  struct sockaddr_in *addr;
  int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
  ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
  addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;

  // inet_pton() returns 1 on success
  // network address was successfully converted
  int s;
  s = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr->sin_addr);
  if (s <= 0) {
    if (s == 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "Set IP %s not in presentation format\n", ip);
    else
      perror ("inet_pton");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (ioctl(fd, request, &ifr) != 0) { // SIOCSIFADDR
    perror ("ioctl");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);

  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
  ifr.ifr_flags |= (IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING);
  ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);
  return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to grant your program with root privilege using following commands in your Makefile or command line:

```
$ sudo chown root your_program
$ sudo chmod a+xs your_program
```

Otherwise, you will get a error message `ioctl: Operation not permitted`